# Local CocoaPod Spec Failing

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I've written a small library that will be used by multiple iOS apps.

I've configured the spec to the best of my knowledge, and imagine it should work, but it's not.

Here is the spec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|                                                                                                                                    
  s.name                  = 'TheLib'                                                                                                                  
  s.version               = '1.0.0'                                                                                                                     
  s.ios.deployment_target = '5.0'                                                                                                                       
  s.source_files          = 'Source/**/*.{h,m}'                                                                                                         
  s.resources             = 'Source/View/Storyboard/*.storyboard'                                                                                       
  s.dependency     'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3.3'                                                                                                           
  s.dependency     'SDWebImage', '~> 3.5'                                                                                                               
  s.dependency     'FrameAccessor', '~> 1.2.0'                                                                                                          
  s.dependency     'NSDate+TimeAgo', '~> 1.0.2'                                                                                                         
end
```

The root simply houses the spec and the Source dir, the latter which contains dirs of .h & .m.

When I run `pod spec lint`, I get:

````
――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 0.26.2
        Ruby : ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin13.0]
    RubyGems : 2.0.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
       Xcode : 5.0.1 (5A2053)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 50abc95a6583527b26b4f80c0a1e4e77052511ba
```

### Error

```
TypeError - can't dup NilClass
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:149:in `dup'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:149:in `downloader'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:101:in `download_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:64:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:263:in `install_source_of_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:237:in `install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:73:in `titled_section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:236:in `install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:103:in `download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:52:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:101:in `download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:87:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:209:in `install_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:177:in `perform_extensive_analysis'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:173:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:173:in `perform_extensive_analysis'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:63:in `validate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/command/spec.rb:83:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/command/spec.rb:78:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/command/spec.rb:78:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/claide-0.3.2/lib/claide/command.rb:206:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:51:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.26.2/bin/pod:19
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing github issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=can%27t+dup+NilClass&type=Issues
````

But, reading the 3 posts on that GitHub page yield no answers. It's as if the source isn't getting added or something (NilClass?).

When I run `pod install` in the project dir that uses the library, with this podfile:

```
pod 'TheLib', :path => '../TheLib'
```

and open the workspace, Xcode has all of the deps correctly installed, but has a directory called "Development Pods", which contains a "TheLib" dir, that has just 4 dummy files.

As seen here:

[image: Dev Pods]

Answer (score 0):

`pod spec lint` by default works by downloading the code from the remote source, not using the local project.

The backtrace you posted shows that the exception is being thrown in the method `install_source_of_pod`, which is subsequently calling `download_source`—this would be trying to download the project from the remote source, which is failing because you haven't yet specified provided the `source` attribute of your spec.

Providing [a valid `source` attribute](http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html#source) should fix this particular error.